# How to arrange my Gtk Widget for my chat application

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

Hie Guys. I am learning `C`, `Gtk+` and `CSS for Gtk` through designing a chat application. This is the GUI that i have designed so far:
[image]

What I am now trying to achive is separating the chat messages such that the sender's message appears of the left while the account owner's appears on the right like what we "usually" see in WhatApp, Pidgin ,etc.
I Tried using a `GtkGrid` that has two columns to divide the messages but the problem is that it don't give me 100% of what I want because:

1. when the message on the left is very large it shrinks the message on the right (which I find okay if the right message is smaller) or vice versa.

> 2. THE ACTUAL PROBLEM : When both messages are very large, the window
>      width increases or the scrollbar appears.

I tried the `GtkGrid` approach on `Glade` app and got this:
[image]

To demonstrate my problem in a more articulate way, I edited a widget picture using `GIMP` so that you see what I really need in my app. I want the messages to overlap such that if the sender 's messages are very large it overlaps onto the receiver's message area (and vice versa) but it should conform to a certain overlaping distance like in my `GIMP` edit below: 
[image]

Also I used the buttons for the message widget so if I am doing it wrong please help. Thank you.

Comment: Right, buttons aren't the right tool for displaying content like this. You might be able to get away with it using labels, word-wrapping, and CSS, but you might be better off using something like Clutter or WebKit(2)GTK+. I don't know what Empathy uses, for comparison.

Comment: Or rather a GtkTextView which can align layouts exactly how they want (and what Pidgin uses).

Comment: Sorry guys I was away.  Thanks for your response. @andlabs I implemented the message bubble using a label as you said but came to an impasse when I tried to search through the all the message labels. Will try const `gchar *text = gtk_button_get_label (...);`  but the chat can be very long.

Comment: @TingPing are you suggesting that I use a single textview and then justify the text to the left or right. like:  `gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(app_state->text_view), GTK_JUSTIFY_RIGHT);` It will be a good thing because I will be able to search the whole textview when I need to but now how do I create a chat bubble around the text.

Comment: You can apply a GtkTextTag to a paragraph and they can have their own justifications. As for the bubble I don't know off the top of my head a good way to do that.

Comment: Thanks will try that tonight